# Text alignment issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment, protrusion

I have been having trouble getting some text to line up correctly and was hoping I could get some assistance with this. My code is below, as well as a screenshot of the output. I've highlighted the text to better show where the edges are.

```
\begin{flushleft}
``The time has come,'' the Walrus said,\\
``To talk of many things:\\
Of shoes, and ships, and ceiling wax,\\
Of cabbages and kings.\\
And why the sea is boiling hot,\\
And whether pigs have wings.''
\end{flushleft}
```

[image: Alignment issue]

This should all be left aligned, but instead lines 1, 3 & 4 are aligned to a certain point, lines 5 & 6 are aligned to a slightly different point, and line 2 is aligned to a slightly different point again. How can I fix this?

Edited to add: it appears the 'microtype' package is loaded in the template I am using. This may be the cause of this and other related problems.

Comment: You can use a `tabular`: \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
``The time has come,'' the Walrus said,\\
``To talk of many things:\\
Of shoes, and ships, and ceiling wax,\\
Of cabbages and kings.\\
And why the sea is boiling hot,\\
And whether pigs have wings.''
\end{tabular}
\end{document}`. Is that an option?

Comment: The code you show would align the  quotes on the first two lines at the same point using the standard definition  of `flushleft` so if you are getting that output the problem is in code you have not shown.  Please always provide a _complete_ small document that demonstrates the problem so people can reproduce/debug. The `O` and the `A` look like natural variation in the font sidebearings but again impossible to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: I am still very new to LaTeX, so I'm not sure what code would be relevant. If it helps, [this is the template I used](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-template-for-cambridge-university-engineering-department-cued-latex-xelatex-and-lualatex-support/kgfqybfnqkdf#.VegMtWfCtdA).

Could you perhaps instead suggest possible code that could interact with this sort of thing to produce a result like this? That would give me a start to help me track down the source of this bug.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you for your suggestion. I don't believe 'tabular' would be a suitable workaround as I am also seeing this issue when I centralise text - I get tiny little non-uniform offsets that mean things aren't quite perfectly centralised.

Comment: Given the complexity of that template I would take this up with the author, who seems to have an active issues list on github.

Comment: If you want to try to track down the bug on your own, you could follow some of the suggestions [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: @Thruston Thank you for your help. At this stage I'm trying to track down the bug myself. So far I've put my above code into an unmodified copy of the template, and still get the error, so I'm somewhat relieved that I can rule out all the modifications I made. The next step I'm considering is to build up my own template, and just gradually copy across just the bits I need, which should leave behind a lot of the unnecessary baggage, and hopefully some of the bugs, or at the very least give me a much more precise idea of where the issue lies. I'll report back once I know more.

Comment: Just to provide some follow up for this: I chose to write my own template from scratch and actually managed to create something that works well, does everything I need it to, and has none of the many bugs in the above template, of which this was just one. (As a beginner I honestly expected I was biting off more than I could chew, but not so!) I never managed to find out what was causing the bug, but as this bug is not present in my template I no longer need to so won't be pursuing this. Thank you for all the help you've provided. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: @AndrewSwann It was mentioned in a previous comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-template-for-cambridge-university-engineering-department-cued-latex-xelatex-and-lualatex-support/kgfqybfnqkdf#.VegMtWfCtdA

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sticking into the left margin of the second line comes from the character protrusion feature. Very likely package `microtype` is loaded.

The protrusion of the first line is prevented by `\begin{flushleft}`, which adds an invisible empty box at the very beginning of the paragraph. This can be seen by `\showlists` with `\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen\showboxdepth=\maxdimen`. The start of the line:

```
\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x345.0, glue set 87.81987fil
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\glue 0.0
..\glue 0.0
..\glue -5.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\glue 5.0
.\penalty 0
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 \ (ligature ``)
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 T
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 h
.\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
```

The protrusion works, when the penalty and the box are removed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
\noindent
\unpenalty\begingroup\setbox0=\lastbox\endgroup
``The time has come,'' the Walrus said,\\
``To talk of many things:\\
Of shoes, and ships, and ceiling wax,\\
Of cabbages and kings.\\
And why the sea is boiling hot,\\
And whether pigs have wings.''
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or with changing the definition of `flushleft`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\flushleft{%
  \everypar=\expandafter{%
    \the\everypar
    \unpenalty
    \begingroup
      \setbox0=\lastbox
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
``The time has come,'' the Walrus said,\\
``To talk of many things:\\
Of shoes, and ships, and ceiling wax,\\
Of cabbages and kings.\\
And why the sea is boiling hot,\\
And whether pigs have wings.''
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The package 'microtype' does indeed appear to be loaded. Unfortunately I am not in a position to test your solution, as I am no longer using this template, but thank you anyway.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what the microtype package actually does, and therefore whether it's useful or not. It seems the simplest solution to this problem would be to just not load this package. What sort of effect would this have on the rest of the document?

Comment: @Ulysses Protrusion feature, this should make the left and right edges of a text block *appear* more smooth. HZ algorithm: additional stretch and shrink capabilities of letters, this makes easier and better line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @DavidCarlisle in a comment, `flushleft` alone won't cause this and the the quotes on the first two lines should align at the same point. `\raggedright`, on the other hand, doesn't have that behavior and works fine in most situations.

You can simply do this (without `microtype`):

```
\documentclass{article}     
\begin{document}

{\raggedright%
``The time has come,'' the Walrus said,\\
``To talk of many things:\\
Of shoes, and ships, and ceiling wax,\\
Of cabbages and kings.\\
And why the sea is boiling hot,\\
And whether pigs have wings.''
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or this (with `\usepackage{microtype}`):

[image]