# What typographic warts can arise from adding microtype to a project?

Tags: typography, microtype

I and co-authors are considering adding `\usepackage{microtype}` to a large book, since we agree that in general it’s a typographic improvement.

However, we want to make sure microtype doesn’t make things *worse* anywhere.  (The current version of the book has already been out for a while, and carefully proofread for layout issues.)

Since it may change line-breaks and hence paragraphs/pagination, we at least need to check again for overfull hboxes and bad widows and orphans.  **Are there any other kinds of infelicities likely to arise from adding `microtype`, that we should be looking out for?**

Comment: I would generally recommend to load `\usepackage[babel]{microtype}` after loading `\usepackage[...]{babel}`. This makes sure that the correct spacing patterns are loaded for your language (e.g. larger space after full stop in English, spaces around "!" and "?" in French). This brings up one additional problem when you do this and the main language of your book is English. The additional space will be added after **every** full stop. That means you have to escape full stops after abbreviations (`as shown e.g.\ by`) to add extra space **only** at the end of sentences.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Don't you have to escape full stops after abbreviations anyway in TeX?  In my experience, even without babel, TeX adds some extra space after every full stop unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: @MikeShulman It depends. I think the extra spacing is standard without babel, simply because TeX after all is an English program. And yes, I always do that and I think it is good practice. However, I know many people who don't and when using babel with a language where there is no extra space after sentence-ends (e.g. German) is it not strictly speaking necessary.

Comment: if you don't like the wider spacing after full stops, you can always apply `\frenchspacing`, which makes all spaces uniform.  insert that *after* `microtype` of course.

Comment: I was having some ugly alignment issues with a document a while back and eventually found `microtype` to be responsible. Example (lines 1 & 2): http://i.stack.imgur.com/0GXkI.png
I would only recommend using microtype if you're willing to go through and proofread every single line all over again, and manually fix every issue. I would argue that any improvements gained from using microtype are too subtle for it to be worthwhile, especially for a large book that would be very time consuming to proofread.

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Sure, but your first comment specifically said that *when the language is English* there is an *additional* problem coming from babel+microtype, which I don't think is right -- if the language is English, then you should already be getting extra spaces after full stops unless they are escaped.

Comment: @Ulysses: your example is just the kind of thing I was looking for!  Could you expand your comment to an answer?

Comment: Sorry, there's not a lot more I can add. I don't know much about microtype, just what my own experiences were with it. If it helps, below is the post I made when I was trying to diagnose my own issue. The responses there may be able to give you a bit more detail. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268835/text-alignment-issue

Comment: @Ulysses Your example shows that you have to be careful with certain combinations (e.g. changing text-alignment) in combination with microtype. However, it also shows what exactly microtype is _supposed_ to do, namely correcting the alignment such that it is _optically_ coherent. Since some letters and symbols have other grey-values than others, they have to protrude further into the margin to give the visual impression of alignment (a common example are dahes at the end of lines, which will protrude into the margin considerably more when compared with letters because they are much thinner).

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf: the problem in Ulysses’ example is that the first two lines are not aligned, even though they begin with exactly the same characters — this is *not* the intended effect (unlike the varying protrusion of the later lines, which is indeed the desired correction for optical coherence).  The cause is an unfortunate interaction with `flushleft`, as described (with a fix) in the answer to the question linked in Ulysses’ second comment.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, I consider `microtype` a very safe addition. It rarely makes things worse and it generally makes things better. But rarely is not never.

Protrusion can be problematic because it does not work everywhere and this can lead to visual inconsistencies which may be more distracting than non-optically aligned text.

`flushleft` has already been mentioned. The default definitions for section headings also disable protrusion in most classes, including the standard ones.

For example,

[image: protrusion oddities]

shows that protrusion is disabled by `\section*{}`. This may not be a big issue. For example, you might always number headings or you might be centring them or you might have the first line of paragraphs following such headings indented. In any of those cases, the discrepancy is much less likely to be noticeable. Moreover, it is relatively unusual to start section headings with punctuation, where the effect tends to be most pronounced.

This can be fixed. For example, I patch the default sectioning from the standard classes to enable protrusion.

[image: fixed sectioning]

This also works with some other classes. For example, I believe it works with Memoir. It does ***not*** work with `titlesec`.

The other thing to note is that you can choose which features to enable and which not. So you could use `microtype`'s font expansion features, say, without using protrusion.

Finally, the effects of protrusion are font-dependent. I've deliberately used a font which has tailored protrusion settings. If you are using a font which does not, the generic settings will be used, if protrusion is enabled. In that case, the settings are more conservative and the effects less pronounced. Of course, this means that the benefits of protrusion are smaller, because `microtype` errs on the side of not-correcting rather than correcting, but it also means that the discrepancies between text where protrusion is disabled and the same text where it is enabled will be less marked.

Complete code:

```
\begin{filecontents}{microtype-standard-sectioning-fix.sty}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{svn-prov}
\ProvidesPackageSVN{$Id: microtype-standard-sectioning-fix.sty 3779 2015-08-27 16:16:40Z cfr $}[\filebase \revinfo]

\def\@ssect#1#2#3#4#5{% modified from latex.ltx - for starred sections below chapter level
  \@tempskipa #3\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #4{%
        \interlinepenalty \@M \noindent #5\@@par}%
    \endgroup
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{#4{%
                \cfr@microfix@sec{#1}#5}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#3}}
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{% modified from latex.ltx - for unstarred sections below chapter level
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
                \@hangfrom{\cfr@microfix@sec{#3}\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
          #6{\cfr@microfix@sec{#3}%
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
\newcommand*\cfr@microfix@sec[1]{%
  \ifdim#1=0pt
        \noindent
  \else
        \hskip #1\relax
  \fi}

\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{cfr-lm,babel,tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{microtype,microtype-standard-sectioning-fix}
\begin{document}
\section*{`Quotable phrases'}
`Quotable phrases'

\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw [opacity=.5, thin, gray!50!blue] (current page text area.south west) -- (current page text area.north west); }
\end{document}
```